# Rerun a function while a list still has elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, while-loop

I think this may be a fairly trivial issue but I am still quite new to Node and Javascript.

I have a list and a function as follows:

```
var my_list = [1, 7, 9, 112, 15, 17, 19, 25, ...]
// Main search function
const search = async(_) => {
  // Loop from ID 1 to X
  for (let index = 1; index < 10000; index++) {
    if (my_index.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
      // Try to find a brewery with this ID
      const brewery = await findBreweriesById(index);
      // If it's found ..
      if (brewery) {
        console.log(brewery.brewery_name);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Nothing found for ID ${index}..`);
    }
  }
  console.log("Finished searching!");
};

search();
```

The function is going to be running as a call to a rate limited API which means not all values in `my_list` will be fetched at once. I have to repeat the fetching function. What I want to do is to be able to remove any successfully fetched value from the main list, i.e. `my_list` and rerun the function until all values in `my_list` have been fetched.

I know two things,

1. I need to remove the fetched index element from the list. I have figured out I could do this using `my_list.splice(indexOf(index),1)`
2. I know I can use a while loop but I have no idea where exactly I'd put it and what condition to set. This also confuses me as to where exactly then I would be splicing to remove the element.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
To be more specific, the API call is rate limited to 100 calls per minute. After that it returns a `429 Too many requests`. So I want to remove all the `200` returns and recycle, i.e. rerun the function for the 429 which should remain in the list.

Comment: `while(my_list.length > 0)`

Comment: what is `good` variable? where was it declared?

Comment: By "rate limit" do you mean number of returns or limited by requests per time period etc. please clarify

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i edited the post to add the explanation for rate limiting. It s number of calls per minute. So the response code goes from 200 to 429 after 100 values in the list and resumes several indexes after that. I want to remove the 200s from the my_list and and leave the 429s in the list and rerun the function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```js
var my_list = [ 1, 7, 9, 112, 15, 17, 19, 25 ]

// Main search function
const search = async _ => {
  while( my_list.length > 0 ){
    const index = my_list[my_list.length - 1]
  
    // Try to find a brewery with this ID
    const brewery = await findBreweriesById(index);
    if (brewery) {
      my_list.splice(indexOf(index),1)
      console.log(brewery.brewery_name);     
    } else {
      console.log(`Nothing found for ID ${index}..`);
    }
  }
}

search();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).